# Android - native sockets not removing 3G-sleep-mode on first attempt

Tags: android, sockets, android-ndk, native, 3g

I have a really annoying problem.
What happens is I have an application which is using native sockets to send data over TCP. 
When I first launch my application and send data over the sockets, nothing gets through. However if I then quit the process and restart it and then send again, it works. Same thing if I open the browser or something before starting my app for the first time after sleep mode.

How do I 'force' 3G to go out of sleep mode before I make the call to the native code?

EDIT: I have already tried with PowerManager.

Comment: Have you tried this on some other device? I have some related problems with native UDP socket on my HTC Desire, but no problems on several Samsung Galaxys, Huawei's or Sony Ericsson phones.

Comment: I have tried this on HTC Desire and HTC EVO 3d. Both have this problem

Comment: Maybe just expect the first try to fail, and then retry a second or two later? Or, issue a dummy HttpGetRequest to www.example.com, say, to wake up the networking layers before trying your real network code.

Comment: There has to be a better way though, it feels too gimmicky

Answer (score 0):

Try calling startUsingNetworkFeature (int networkType, String feature) On a ConnectivityManager and wait for it to be available before you bind your sockets ect......

[Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#startUsingNetworkFeature%28int,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

I'd give the ConnectivityManager API `requestRouteToHost(int networkType, int hostAddress)` a try.